# 72 уязвимости после установки react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

После выполнения npm install react-router-dom в терминале вижу сообщение о 72 уязвимостях. Из них 12 - незначительные, 19 - средний уровень (или модерируются), 37 - высокий уровень и 4 критические.

Все, конечно, запускается, но что это означает? Можно ли это исправить?
[image: скриншот из терминала с уведомлением об уязвимостях]

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Работает - не трогай

Comment: версия какая? как ты устоновливал?